# Route audio to specific device output on OS X

Tags: objective-c, osx-mountain-lion, core-audio, avplayer, avasset

Am looking to add a preview channel to an AV project, so that a video or audio file can be playing on the master output channel but the user can preview a separate audio or video file on a different channel.

Naturally the prerequisite is that the user has a sound device capable of multiple channels or a separate device for master output than for preview.  For example, the output could go to a USB audio device which provides balanced audio output but the preview could be via the standard headphone jack.

I am struggling to find the right documentation on enumerating sound devices connected to the mac and then linking either AVAudioPlayer or AVPlayer/AVPlayerLayer or an underlying API.

Anyone know where I should be looking?

Is this a case of discovering the sound devices, selecting the appropriate one then using something like `NSSound` to set the device before I start playing the file?  What happens with files already playing?

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to look at AVAudioSession.  See the section on Working with Audio Channels.  This should point you in the right direction: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240

Comment: any luck on doing that?

Comment: I wasn't able to get this done using any of the high level classes and had to start looking at the low level versions of CG but ran into a dead end.  Can't be that hard, applications like Serato etc do this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `AVAudioSession` is iOS-only.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the audio output device for a given AVPlayer instance by setting the instance property 'audioOutputDeviceUniqueID' to the UniqueID of the desired device. This also works for AVAudioPlayer.

I can confirm that it works as expected in MacOS 10.11.6, using Key-Value coding ( setValue:forKey:). The AVAudioPlayer API also has a specific method to do this 'setCurrentDevice:'

The messiest part of the process is obtaining the list of valid UniqueIDs for the current system. 0 always means' System Default", but any other specific device is identified by a CF$ that appears to be constructed by CoreAudio at runtime using the a combination of manufacturer's name, product name, and a bunch of other mysterious codes. The process to get the current list is described here: [AudioObjectGetPropertyData to get a list of input devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575408/audioobjectgetpropertydata-to-get-a-list-of-input-devices/4577271)

### Apple's doc on 'audioOutputDeviceUniqueID' :

Instance Property
audioOutputDeviceUniqueID
Specifies the unique ID of the Core Audio output device used to play audio.

Declaration
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *audioOutputDeviceUniqueID;
Discussion
The default value of this property is nil, indicating that the default audio output device is used. Otherwise the value of this property is a string containing the unique ID of the Core Audio output device to be used for audio output.

Core Audio's kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceUID is a suitable source of audio output device unique IDs.

---

Answer (score 0):

Please check [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio).

There is EZMicrophone and EZOutput.

By using them, you can route audio to specific device output on OS X.