# Selecting external mic in AudioUnit in mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-audio, audiounit

I am trying to set the external mic for MAC using the AudioUnit.
I have googled and found that it is possible to set the default input device on mac using https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2091/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003118-CH1-CURRENTDEVICE

But the problem is that the example on the link is setting the default mac mic. but i am trying to choose the mic myself and it can be either default of user choice. I am able to get the list of connecting input device from the stackoverflow post [AudioObjectGetPropertyData to get a list of input devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575408/audioobjectgetpropertydata-to-get-a-list-of-input-devices)

But i am not able to get any api which sets the mic option of my choice in the list.
Can somebody help me to find a solution for this or a link to an example.

Comment: If you have the `AudioDeviceID` for the desired input mic just use that in your call to `AudioUnitSetProperty`.  If you need the ID from UID use `kAudioHardwarePropertyDeviceForUID`

Comment: sbooth, Can you share an example code for the same, a few line of codes will be really helpful for me and peoples like me who as stuck in similar issues,

Comment: Do you want code to set the device or convert the UID to the device ID?