# How to access multiple buffers in UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList> (non-mutable)

Tags: swift, core-audio

I've been trying to use the new `AVAudioSinkNode` in Core Audio.
It passes `audioBufferList` which is of type `UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList>` to the closure handling the audio.

The implementation of `AudioBufferList` in Swift is such that you *cannot* access multiple buffers, if there are more than one. Apple provided a wrapper for the mutable version, `UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>`, which is called `UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer` and allows access to multiple buffers.

But I cannot find a relevant wrapper that I could use with the non-mutable `UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList>`....

```
let sinkNode = AVAudioSinkNode() { (timestamp, frames, audioBufferList) -> OSStatus in
    // audioBufferList is UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList>
    // how to access multiple buffers in audioBufferList?
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access each `AudioBuffer` in an `AudioBufferList` in Swift, you may choose two ways:

- Do some pointer operations yourself and calculate each address of `AudioBuffer`.
- Use `UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer` forcefully.

If you could find a right sample code before `UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer` was introduced in Swift, the first way might be your option, but as for now, it's hard to find one.

---

To use `UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer` forcefully, you may need to convert `UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList>` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>`, which is not too difficult:

```
            let audioBufferListPtr = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: audioBufferList))
```

I believe you know how to access buffers once you get `UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer`.

**Caution:** Even if type conversion from `UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList>` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>` is easily made, the actual region passed through `audioBufferList` is not mutable. You may need extra care not to mutate such region.

Comment: That's excellent! This is all I needed: `let audioBufferListPtr = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: audioBufferList))` -- Thanks so much!

Comment: You've been of tremendous help!!! :) Any opinion on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837320/avaudiosinknode-with-non-default-but-still-device-native-sample-rates