# AVAudioSinkNode with non-default, but still device-native sample rates

Tags: swift, core-audio, avaudioengine

I've configured `AVAudioSinkNode` attached to `AVAudioEngine`'s `inputNode` like so:

```
let sinkNode = AVAudioSinkNode() { (timestamp, frames, audioBufferList) -> OSStatus in
    print("SINK: \(timestamp.pointee.mHostTime) - \(frames) - \(audioBufferList.pointee.mNumberBuffers)")
    return noErr
}

audioEngine.attach(sinkNode)
audioEngine.connect(audioEngine.inputNode, to: sinkNode, format: nil)
audioEngine.prepare()

do {
    try audioEngine.start()
    print("AudioEngine started.")
} catch {
    print("AudioEngine did not start!")
}
```

I've separately configured it to use the "Built-in Microphone" device (which I am sure it does use).

If I set sample rate 44100 for the mic (using "Audio MIDI Setup" app provided by Apple on all Macs), everything works as expected:

```
AudioEngine started.
SINK: 692312319180567 - 512 - 2
SINK: 692312348024104 - 512 - 2
SINK: 692312359634082 - 512 - 2
SINK: 692312371244059 - 512 - 2
SINK: 692312382854036 - 512 - 2
...
```

However, if I use "Audio MIDI Setup" app (provided by Apple on all Macs), and change the mic's sample rate to anything **other than 44100 (say 48000)**, then the sink node **doesn't seem to do anything** (doesn't print anything).

Of course, originally I was trying to modify the mic's sample rate programmatically. But later on I discovered that the same happens when I just change the device sample rate via the standard "Audio MIDI Setup" app. Therefore, the code I have for setting the sample rate is unnecessary to post here.

Does anyone know if `AVAudioSinkNode` has **allowed sample rate hard-coded into it**?

I cannot find any other explanation...

Answer (score 3):

I've been toying around with AVAudioSinkNodes and it doesn't appear to me to be restricted to a 44100 sampling rate.

In my case, when I check the sampling rate of my input and sink nodes after attaching them, I get the following:

```
Input node sample rates: 
    IF <AVAudioFormat 0x600002527700:  2 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32, non-inter> 
    OF <AVAudioFormat 0x60000250fac0:  2 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32, non-inter>

Sink node sample rates: 
    IF <AVAudioFormat 0x60000250fbb0:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter> 
    OF <AVAudioFormat 0x60000250fb60:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter>
```

But once I connected them together, I got the following:

```
Input node sample rates: 
    IF <AVAudioFormat 0x600002527980:  1 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32> 
    OF <AVAudioFormat 0x600002506760:  2 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32, non-inter>

Sink node sample rates: 
    IF <AVAudioFormat 0x600002506710:  2 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32, non-inter> 
    OF <AVAudioFormat 0x600002505db0:  2 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32, non-inter>
```

I'm new to working with audio frameworks, but this does seem to suggest that the sink node's sample rate isn't hardcoded.

Your connection,

```
audioEngine.connect(audioEngine.inputNode, to: sinkNode, format: nil)
```

seems to differ from mine. Rightly or wrongly, I explicitly specified the format as `audioEngine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)` which led to the settings shown. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks this put me on the right track, but I needed to use `audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)` (rather than `outputFormat`) as my mic sample rate was different than my output device sample rate.